# Script task won't open Editor in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, vsta

I am using SSIS 2014 and Visual Studio 2013. When I click on Edit Script button of script task no error nothing happens but script editor doesn't open. Nothing happens I have installed on my machine:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012
- Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications x64 Runtime 3.0

Comment: Is this on a brand new project/package?

Comment: Brand new project in Visual studio 2013 SSIS 2014

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this same exact issue. Try installing Sql Server Data Tools 2012 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) as well as Sql Server Data Tools 2013 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313). I am not sure why you would need both but for some reason the script task when only having SSDT 2013 installed still seemed to want to reference 2012 (see screen shot below).

Hopefully this helps.

[image]

Comment: After installing the SQL Server Data Tools my VS 2013 tries to open VS2012 after pressing "Edit Script". Here I get the message "This program has known compatibility issues. "Check for solutions online" gives me nothing and "Run Program" starts VS2012.

Comment: One reason that someone might need both SSDT 2012 and 2013 is because using SSDT 2013 you cannot work with SSIS packages for SQL Server 2012 and lower. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/03/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx  This is a serious PITA.

Comment: Have a VS 2019 install with the latest SSDT, still had to install SSDT 2012 to edit the script.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem with the following setup:

- Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition (15.6.6)
- SSDT 2017 (15.5.2)
- SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition

I solved repairing the installation of **Visual Studio Tools for Application 2017** from the control panel:

[image]

Comment: This also solved the problem for me with Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.7) and SSDT 2017 (14.0)

Comment: Had the same issue, the "Edit Script" button simply was not doing anything. I had no error message or any sort of indication that something happen. Reparing fixed the issue.

Comment: This fixed my issue, as well.

Comment: Thank you so much !! After 3 days reinstalling VS 2017 and SSDT this solved my problem too.

Comment: Extra emphasis on NOT using the Visual Studio Installer, but the Windows Control Panel!

Answer (score 8):

I've just had exactly the same problem.  I've got both SSDT and SSDT BI installed for VS2012 and VS2013 but still couldn't get the Edit Script to open.  I repaired my install of VSTA 2012 and also newly installed VSTA 2013 but still no luck.
**Turns out I just had to run VS 2013 as administrator and it worked!**  Might not be the solution for all but worth a try if you've got all the correct applications installed.

Comment: what if I dont have admin privileges? Will it be enough to ask the admin to give me full privileges on the application?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup VS 2013 Professional, with SQL 2014 Data Tools.  My VstaProjects window would open, but the ScriptMain.vb window, with the framework, would not open.
Repair was not an option, so the tech removed and reinstalled SSDT 2014.  It works now.