# Edit Script... button in SSDT 2013 won't work

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I've been doing some self directed learning in SSDT 2013 and for some reason the Edit Script button won't work.
I've read through some threads, the closest being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743737/script-task-wont-open-editor-in-visual-studio-2013) and also took up some advice about opening the software as Administrator but still it won't work.
Moreover, I tried to install SSDT 2012 but apparently I have that already loaded but can't find it in my apps bar.
Does anyone have any further ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What are the symptoms - how is it not working? Worth adding a screenshot?

Comment: One thing to check is that the ssdt installer actually installed Visual studio 2012. There is a VS2012 IDE shell that acts as your script editor in vs2013 ssdt projects. If this is not present then you will need to uninstall ssdt and reinstall and select that it is a new sql instance install. This will do two things 1 create any sdk hooks for vs 2013. 2 install vs2012 IDE shell.

Comment: 2 install vs2012 IDE shell. Done and working thanks.